# Get All the Reports Metadata Backup

Tags: apex, salesforcedx, metadata-api, vs-code

Want to get all reports metadata from Salesforce, tried with VS code Org Browser, but it doesn't get me all the Reports.

SELECT Count() FROM Report fetches 10000+ Reports

Appreciate any help/workaround

Answer (score 1):

Using VSCode with the Org connection established, you may navigate to Reports -> Select Folder you want to backup -> Click on the Download icon next to specific Reports Folder and Report. However, considering the volume mentioned above, this approach makes almost no sense.

Alternatively, you may download all together using a manifest file with all reports-related configurations listed there. The most simple way to generate a manifest file in this case is using the [Salesforce Package.xml Generator Extension for VS Code](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=VignaeshRamA.sfdx-package-xml-generator). Having this plugin installed allows you to generate a manifest file with all Reports and Report Types available for you (Private reports will not be included). Once you have the manifest file generated, you may pull metadata using VSCode/CLI/Workbench.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Package builder](https://packagebuilder.herokuapp.com/) to build package.xml file of your org metadata. Once you have full metadata you can copy list of all [reports](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_meta.meta/api_meta/meta_report.htm) something like below.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Package xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
    <types>
        <members>MyReportFolder/MyReportName</members>
        <members>unfiled$public/Report</members>
        <members>Testfolder/Report1</members>
        <members>Testing/Report2</members> 
        <name>Report</name>
    </types>
    <version>60.0</version>
</Package>
```

Once you have list of all reports of your org use VS Code/ANT migration to retrieve metadata.